# How should I set the bits when doing software protection?

Tags: avr, atmel, atmelstudio

I am using atmel studio and usbasp.I am using this code:

```
C:\WinAVR-20100110\bin\avrdude -c usbasp -p t85 -Ulock:w:0x00:m
```

You can look picture for settings lock bits in datasheet.

[image is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8Jgh.png)

You can look picture.Is there a difference between making 0x00 and 0xfc?I am not sure.

0x00= 00000000

0xfc= 11111100

The important thing is the 0th and 1st bits.Other bits have dashes.What does that mean?Does it matter if other bits 0 or 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bits 2 through 6 are not implemented in the chip and cannot be programmed, so it does not matter what values you put there, as long as your version of AVRDUDE accepts your command.  Depending on what version of AVRDUDE you use, those bits are either ignored, or you are forced to make them be 0, or you are forced to make them be 1.

Comment: Hello,David thanks for reply.How I can read lock bits with usbasp?
for example I can read low fuse bits this code:
C:\WinAVR-20100110\bin\avrdude -c usbasp -p t85 -U lfuse:r:lfuse.hex:i -v
But lock bits I don't know.

Comment: Please click the checkmark on my answer if it answered your original question.  As for your new question, I assume you just replace `lfuse:r` with `lock:r`.  If that doesn't work, please ask a new question; StackOverflow is not a forum.

Comment: David I have tried lock:r but I have reached same results.This different commands:

C:\WinAVR-20100110\bin\avrdude -c usbasp -p t85 -Ulock:w:0x00:m

I have used 0xff and 0xfc instead of 0x00
But results same

Results::01000000E21D
:00000001FF  Why?

Comment: I think my answer successfully explains how to write lock bits, especially if you can see that AVRDUDE is verifying them as it writes them.  So I think you should accept the answer and then ask a new question.  I can't quite follow what you did from these brief comments so it would be better to write it all out clearly in a new question.

Comment: When I do 0x00, I get a verification error. After that I will do 0xfc. But I want to ask for a situation where I did 0x00.Is there a problem for the system operation? Even when I did 0x00, the software protection worked correctly. And I did not see a problem with the system operation. Maybe there is something else you know.

Comment: David Grayson,also you can look this picture: https://a.uguu.se/eujuem.jpg I have uploaded two situations.Am I in vain worried that I use a 0x00 instead of a 0xfc? (for operating of system)

Comment: Those pictures seem normal to me.  When your version of AVRDUDE reads the lock bits from the AVR to verify them, it is reading ones for the unimplemented bits, so it will always read a number between 0xFC and 0xFF no matter what you try to write.  Therefore, you should specify 0xFC so that the verification step can succeed without showing errors.  I recommend 0xFC for you.  But 0xFC or 0x00 would both have the same effect on the AVR itself.  Please now click the checkmark to accept my answer.